# Can I use GPU through the M.2 interface (support PCIe) together with GPU installed in normal PCIe x16 slot in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, kvm, gpu-passthrough

I have a Nvidia GPU workstation for multiple users. I use KVM to create 4 VMs and use GPU in VMs in passthrough mode. However, I find when I pass through all 4 GPUs to these VMs. The host system (Ubuntu server LTS 20.04.02) always freeze. So I guess I have to keep at least one GPU on the host (The CPU is TR3960x, does not have integrated GPU).

There is no pcie x16 slot left on the motherboard, so I just install a low-end AMD gpu on a M.2 slot with a M.2 to pcie x16 adapter. But after this, I cannot boot into the host system, with error

```
[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)]
```

I also tried to boot from a USB drive, but got

```
grub error: cannot allocate kernel buffer, you need to load kernel first.
```

Comment: I do not think, but I could be wrong, that these objects were meant to be mated: 'so I just install a low-end AMD gpu on a M.2 slot with a M.2 to pcie x16 adapter' I mean, I see one: https://www.amazon.com/Thsion-Adapter-Power-Cable-Mining/dp/B08PKD5KCH/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=m.2+to+pcie&qid=1615495829&sr=8-2 but note the reviews say "didnt work". I am not sure how it would work, actually. Did you contact the maker of the adapter??

Comment: I think my adapter works fine. I tried only install the GPU on this adapter and I can get display output, though with the same grub error.

Comment: Wow, OK, in that case, when you installed it you moved around the BIOS/EUFI idea of where your drives are... that is the errror you are getting. Most of the time when you throw a new drive in (the BIOS/EUFI may present that device to linux/grub as a disk), the previous drive names change (this is why linux tries to use UUIDs now). I have a feeling the BIOS/EUFI is telling grub its a disk.